# Get file path of open file dialogbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am wanting to get the file directory of an already open file dialog box opened by internet explorer. I used the `FindWindow()` API to get the correct filedialog box. But my question is how to get the file directory from that dialogbox.

I know how to get it from one that was opened using the following.

```
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
```

But not from one that is allready open.

Edit:

Would something like `Dim FileDialog as New msoFileDialogFilePicker` work? I'm not sure if thats the correct Syntax

Comment: How are you opening the file dialog box in IE?  (Do you have code that you haven't included in the question?  Are you relying on the user opening a file dialog in IE, then running your VBScript and/or VBA application?)  If you are relying on the user opening it, how are you ensuring that they haven't already closed it again before your code runs?

Comment: Thanks for the questions! I have a Loop that is using the `FindWindow()` API to check for when it opens. The dialog box has a very unique title. The dialog box is open when the user saves a file that is being downloaded. I'm just not sure how to rip the `.SelectedItems` from one that is not open programmatically.

Comment: @YowE3K Would this be the correct solution? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.filedialog.selecteditems.aspx

Comment: You're working on the assumption that the dialog box used by IE is a MS Office dialog box. But IE isn't part of Office - and I wouldn't be too sure that the window it displays is generated by an object that has a publicly accessible `SelectedItems` property, nor how you would refer to the object that has generated the window even if it did.  (I assume it would require a `GetParent` API function, but I'm not sure whether that would get you a File Dialog object or just a reference to IE itself.)

Comment: @YowE3K So `SaveFileDialog` is the system name of the object how would you referance one that is already open? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry - I have no idea - I try to avoid the API calls whenever possible.  (If I was writing your application, I would have the user tell your Access VBA application where they wanted to save the file, and then have the Access VBA tell IE where to save it.  There are plenty of SO questions about how to do that, so I wouldn't have to waste my brain cells trying to come up with a solution of my own.)

Comment: Well I appreciate the bit of insight you have given.